# Alternatives for "which is .." or "which can be ..." in scientific papers

Tags: conjunctions

I am trying to write an article and I find myself often using the phrases such as:

> 1. ... is the thing which is ...
> 2. ... is the thing which can be used for ...

Is there any alternative patterns for this usage for scientific papers, by separating the sentences or by using different conjunctions?

Comment: *which* -> *that*

Comment: "Employed for/ adopted for/ used for" are some alternatives you may consider.

Comment: Instead of "X is the thing which is Y", say "X is Y"; instead of "X is the thing which can be used for Y", say "X can be used for Y".